# Can I cast a std::array to slice? Or is there anything else I can use instead?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, c++11

Is this undefined behavior?

```
std::array<int, 5> x = {3, 5, 1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 3>& y = *reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 3>*>(&x[1]);
for(int i = 0; i != 3; i++) {
    std::cout << y[i] << "\n";
}
```

Maybe yes, but I really feel like there should be a **safe** way to slice `std::array`s.

**EDIT:** Following Radek's suggestion:

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned start, unsigned end, typename T>
std::array<T, end - start>& array_slice(std::array<T, N>& x)
{
    static_assert(start <= end, "start <= end");
    static_assert(end <= N-1, "end <= N");
    return *reinterpret_cast<std::array<T, end - start>*>(&x[start]);
}
```

**EDIT:** Ok, I decided that I'm unhappy with `std::array`s and will move to something else, any ideas?

Comment: *but I really feel like there should be a safe way to slice std::arrays* write a template function `array_cast`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about a placement new?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array_slice : public std::array<T,N> {
    ~array_slice() = delete; 
};

int main() {
    std::array<double,4> x_mu{0.,3.14,-1.,1.};
    std:: cout << &x_mu << std::endl;

    {
        auto slicer = [] (std::array<double,4>& ref) {
            array_slice<double,3>* p = new (&ref) array_slice<double,3>;
            return p;
        };    

        std::array<double,3>& x_  = *slicer(x_mu);
        std::copy(x_.begin(),x_.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout," "));
        std:: cout << std::endl;
        std:: cout << &x_ << std::endl;
    }

    std::copy(x_mu.begin(),x_mu.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout," "));
}
```

Comment: This is all sorts of undefined behavior.  You end the lifetime of the old array elements by reusing their memory.  You create new elements in the same locations, but the rule allowing existing references/pointers to refer to new objects in the same location only applies to complete objects, and these are subobjects of an aggregate.  Depending on the element type, it may have non-trivial default initialization that wipes out the existing value, or you may end up with uninitialized objects (which cannot be assumed to take the value that previously existed in their memory location).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is undefined behavior. You're taking one type and `reinterpret_cast`ing it to another. Indeed, the use of the `reinterpret_cast` should be a big red flag for "here there be dragons!"

As for slicing arrays, that's not going to happen. A `std::array` contains values; a slice of this would contain *references* to part of that array. And therefore, it would not be a `std::array`. You can *copy* slices of arrays, but not using `std::array`. You would need to use `std::vector`, since it allows the calling of constructors, as well as construction from a range of values. Remember: `std::array` is just a nicer wrapper around a C-style array.

The committee is looking into a template `array_ref<T>` class, which is exactly what it says: a reference to some segment of an array of type `T`. This could be a regular C-style array, a `std::vector`, a `std::array`, or just some memory allocated with `new T[]`. There are [some library implementations of the class already](https://code.google.com/p/cxx1y-array-string-ref/), but nothing is standardized yet.

---

> Following Radek's suggestion:

Hiding the undefined behavior in a function *does not make it defined behavior*. You can try to pretend that it isn't undefined, but it still is. The moment you use that `reinterpret_cast`, you willingly give up living in C++-land.

Comment: I agree with what you say, but I think `std::array` in the standard is basically broken without slicing.

Comment: @Giovanni: It's broken only if you're trying to use it for something it's not meant to be used for. It's like saying that `std::list` is broken because its elements are not stored contiguously, or that `std::map` is broken because it doesn't offer O(1) lookup. You're expecting a hammer to function as a screwdriver.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I'm not talking about hammers. C++'s `std::array`s are supposed to improve C arrays, as in providing MORE functionality (type-checking for compile-time known bounds), and yet something that was perfectly valid with C arrays is not valid with C++ ones anymore for absolutely no reason. I think that pretty much qualifies me to say that the STL API is **broken** in this respect.

Comment: @Giovanni: "something that was perfectly valid with C arrays is not valid with C++ ones" No, it wasn't. It was only "valid" with C arrays when those arrays *decayed* into pointers. At which point they stop being *arrays*; they're pointers. You cannot take an `int[5]` and turn it into an `int[3]`; you can turn it into an `int*`, but that's a different construct. What `std::array` does is remove the decaying into pointers, so that arrays *remain* arrays at all times (unless you explicitly decay them, at which point you willingly give up safety). That's what `array_ref` is all about.

Comment: Cast of `int[5]` to `int[3]` is not undefined behavior. The behavior is only undefined if the pointer evaluation produces an invalid pointer, if the evaluation produces an overflow or if the result points past the last element of the array object's allocated memory. See C99 section 6.5.6.

Comment: @Giovanni: This discussion is about C++11, not C99. And in C++11, casting from `int[5]` to `int[3]` is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal Are you referencing 6.5.6 Additive Operators? If so, this doesn't support that casting from `int[5]` to `int[3]` is well-defined in C99.

Comment: While casting an `int[5]` to an `int[3]` is undefined behavior, it is hard to come up with a reasonable standards-complaint implementation in which an `int[3]` and `int[5]` are not layout-compatible, let alone one that actually exists in the wild.  Can anyone provide one?  `reinterpret_cast` does **not** mean "undefined behavior" if the things being reinterpreted are layout-compatible.